# How to call fileList() method from Context class?

Tags: android, android-context, filelist

How do I use the `fileList()` method from the context class? What am I doing wrong here?

```
Context conData;
    conData = new Context();
    String[] instrumentFileList = new conData().fileList();
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As in Doc:

> **fileList()** :  Returns an array of strings naming the private files
>   associated with this Context's application package.

means you should use Context associated with application to call  `fileList()` instead of by creating `Context` class instance to get list of private files associated with application.

You can get list of files in Activity as:

```
 String[] instrumentFileList = YourActivityName.this.fileList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this from

```
 String[] instrumentFileList = new conData().fileList();
```

to

```
 String[] instrumentFileList = conData().fileList();
```

You have already created instance by this `conData = new Context();`

If `Context` is your non activity class then you can use above code. But you just want to use `Context` of app then you can use `getApplicationContext();`